# Как внутри кода, указать разные данные для продакшена и dev?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Мне нужно в 1 компоненте загрузить файл, но он на разных адресах на dev и work сайте.

```
let geoJsonPath = "/data/moscow-districts.js"; 
  if(WORK_SERVER){
      geoJsonPath = "/work-site/maps/moscow-districts.js";
  }
```

Проект делаю через create-react-app 
Далее собираю yarn build 
Либо запускаю на локале yarn start.

Как определить когда выполняется yarn build, а когда yarn start внутри кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать переменные окружения, например:

```
REACT_APP_MODE_ENV=development yarn start
```

*(Или `set REACT_APP_MODE_ENV=development` для windows)*

А потом ловить ее в коде

```
if(process.env.REACT_APP_MODE_ENV === 'development')
  geoJsonPath = '/work-site/maps/moscow-districts.js'
```

Есть интересный вариант через модуль `dotenv` с бОльшим количеством передаваемых переменных, подробнее [тут](https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d)

Comment: А без передачи параметра можно как то определить?